# Como executar arquivo de áudio utilizando a classe AudioTrack?

Tags: java, android

Pretendo fazer um app de tocar bateria, mas, como estou começando agora a desenvolver para android, estou com dificuldade. 
Eu preciso tocar um arquivo de áudio com a classe `AudioTrack` (pois ela tem a menor latência), porém não entendi como utilizá-la para executar um arquivo **.mp3**, por exemplo.

Já pesquisei, mas só encontrei exemplos da classe `MediaPlayer`. Alguém poderia postar um exemplo da `AudioTrack`?

Answer (score 2):

A única forma de tocar algum áudio pela `AudioTrack` é um *streaming* PCM, como pode ser visto na [documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html):

> The `AudioTrack` class manages and plays a single audio resource for Java applications. It allows streaming of PCM audio buffers to the audio sink for playback. This is achieved by "pushing" the data to the AudioTrack object using one of the `write(byte[], int, int)` and `write(short[], int, int) methods`.

Em tradução livre:

> A classe `AudioTrack` gerencia e toca um recurso de áudio para aplicações Java. Ela permite *streaming* de *buffers* de áudio PCM ser a fonte de áudio para reprodução. Isso pode ser alcançando através do carregamento das informações para um objeto `AudioTrack` usando um dos métodos: `write(byte[], int, int)` e `wirte(short[], int, int)`.

Pode-se utilizar [esse tutorial](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/624/android-audio-play-an-mp3-file-on-an-audiotrack/) para descomprimir o arquivo **.mp3** e carregá-lo como PCM, utilizando a [biblioteca JLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html) e o código abaixo:

```java
public static byte[] decode(String path, int startMs, int maxMs)
  throws IOException, com.mindtherobot.libs.mpg.DecoderException {
  ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);

  float totalMs = 0;
  boolean seeking = true;

  File file = new File(path);
  InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), 8 * 1024);
  try {
    Bitstream bitstream = new Bitstream(inputStream);
    Decoder decoder = new Decoder();

    boolean done = false;
    while (! done) {
      Header frameHeader = bitstream.readFrame();
      if (frameHeader == null) {
        done = true;
      } else {
        totalMs += frameHeader.ms_per_frame();

        if (totalMs >= startMs) {
          seeking = false;
        }

        if (! seeking) {
          SampleBuffer output = (SampleBuffer) decoder.decodeFrame(frameHeader, bitstream);

          if (output.getSampleFrequency() != 44100
              || output.getChannelCount() != 2) {
            throw new com.mindtherobot.libs.mpg.DecoderException("mono or non-44100 MP3 not supported");
          }

          short[] pcm = output.getBuffer();
          for (short s : pcm) {
            outStream.write(s & 0xff);
            outStream.write((s >> 8 ) & 0xff);
          }
        }

        if (totalMs >= (startMs + maxMs)) {
          done = true;
        }
      }
      bitstream.closeFrame();
    }

    return outStream.toByteArray();
  } catch (BitstreamException e) {
    throw new IOException("Bitstream error: " + e);
  } catch (DecoderException e) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Decoder error", e);
    throw new com.mindtherobot.libs.mpg.DecoderException(e);
  } finally {
    IOUtils.safeClose(inputStream);    
  }
}
```

Vale ressaltar que a `AudioTrack` não foi concebida com o intuito de carregar arquivos de áudio. O ideal para carregar arquivos comprimidos de áudio (tais como mp3 e ogg, por exemplo) seriam as classes [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) ou [SoundPoll](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html), como pode ser visto nas [respostas dessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200812/play-audio-mp3-ogg-from-sd-card-with-audiotrack) da SOen.